# import 2007 excel data into sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset

While importing data from excel 2010 into SQL Server 2012 I am getting following error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
>   <

I am using following query:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.headers 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' ,'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\ishu.bhardwaj\Desktop\02.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1' ,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Regards
Ishu Bhardwaj

Comment: Try IMPORT using IMPORT EXPORT SSMS feature instead

Comment: check the following URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888082/ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-m and hope this will help you.

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 0):

**Cause 1**: You may receive this error if the Excel file is currently opened.
**Solution 1**: Close the Excel file if it is currently opened and try executing again.