# Bulk import Excel file into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I am trying to bulk import an Excel file into SQL Server. I have tried a lot of effort but not get proper result. I have ran following query but got an error. Please try to help me I am stuck on this. I have SQL Server 2012 and Excel 2013 installed

```
SELECT * 
INTO temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\File.xls;IMEX=1',
                'SELECT * FROM [Data$]')
```

Error:

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: is this a one-off import, or something you will want to run over and over again ?

Comment: You could try it using the built-in Wizard. You could also try using a .csv file instead. Is there a reason you need an Excel file implicitly?

Comment: @sarin: Yes I want to run it over an over again using stored procedure

Comment: Sounds you got a problem with the provider. Be sure that provider and the  SQL Server you are using are both 64-64 or 32-32 bits

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples for excel versions 97-2010, which should have you covered :

```
--Excel 2007-2010
SELECT * INTO #temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=D:\File.xls',
    'SELECT * FROM [ExcelTabName$]'); -- Replace ExcelTabName with actual tab name

--Excel 97-2003
SELECT * INTO #temptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=D:\File.xls',
    'select * from [ExcelTabName$]'); -- Replace ExcelTabName with actual tab name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is office versions issue just try this code

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Export.xls;', 
                       'SELECT id_sale FROM [ExportSheet$]')
```

[More help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888082/ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-m)